# dev_appserver.py AssertionError (Windows)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

When I type "dev_appserver.py" in windows command prompt I receive:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\computername\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 95, in 
    assert sys.version_info[0] == 2
AssertionError

Why is this? I can't run the program? Why would there be an assertion error. Please help! I can't run a local cloud engine server on windows currently.

For what it's worth I've tried with python 3.7, 3.8, and 2.7... all with the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assert statement `sys.version_info[0] == 2` means that the major version number of Python must be 2, otherwise the program will abort.

You are running the Python program with Python 3. To verify type `python -V`.

Install Python 2 on your system and set up the correct paths, etc. Read the documentation for your system.

[Python 2.7.17 Download](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2717/)

[Hitchhiker's Guide to Installing Python 2 on Windows](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install/win/)

Note: Python 2 has reached its end of life. There is still a lot of software and libraries for Python 2, but be aware that most new development is for Python 3. There are many new features for Python 3 that make the transition worthwhile.

[Sunsetting Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After installing python 2.7 - the command dev_appserver.py still did nothing for me. I had to cd into AppData/Local/Google/CloudSDK/Bin and then run python dev_appserver.py and then it worked. What you noted to remove the error being a python version issue indeed seemed to be true. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Robbie That means that you did not setup the Windows PATH environment variable to point to your Python 2 installation or you did not close and reopen the Windows Command Prompt so that the PATH is re-read. The Python documentation shows how to set up PATH for Windows.